# Passing json array using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am new to android and retrofit and I am facing a lot of problem parsing json array.. I can print the json response in my logcat. and its working fine. I just want to display the image and data now on my device in a cardview. Please I have been struggling with this for more den weeks.. Help me guys. Help me with my code. I dont want to give up.

**pojo class:**

```
public class DetailData {
    public String image;
    public String pname;
    public String pprice;
    public String pdescr;

    public String getPdescr() {
        return pdescr;
    }

    public void setPdescr(String pdescr) {
        this.pdescr = pdescr;
    }

    public String getPprice() {
        return pprice;
    }

    public void setPprice(String pprice) {
        this.pprice = pprice;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**Adapter class:**

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailsAdapter.usersViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DetailData> itemList;
    private Context context1;
    onclickListener mOnclickListener;

    public DetailsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetailData> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context1 = context;
    }

    public void updatevalues(ArrayList<DetailData> newlist) {
        this.itemList = newlist;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public class usersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Bind(R.id.description)
        TextView pdescr;

        @Bind(R.id.image)
        ImageView image;

        @Bind(R.id.pprice)
        TextView pprice;

        @Bind(R.id.parent)
        RelativeLayout parent;

        public usersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            parent.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.parent:
                    mOnclickListener.onCategoryClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition());
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public DetailsAdapter.usersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cat_detaillist, null);
        DetailsAdapter.usersViewHolder viewHolder = new DetailsAdapter.usersViewHolder(layoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(usersViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DetailData current = itemList.get(position);
        holder.pdescr.setText(current.getPdescr());
        holder.pprice.setText(current.getPprice());
       // holder.pdescr.setText(current.getPdescr());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }


    public interface onclickListener {
        void onCategoryClick(View v, int position);
    }


    public void setOnItemClickListener(final onclickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnclickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

**Activity class:**

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
    Call<ResponseBody> call;
    DetailsAdapter rcAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<DetailData> adapterList = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;


    private static final String JSON_BED = "http://localhost/shree_decor/jsonfetch.php";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cat_detail);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int catid = i.getExtras().getInt("catid");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rcAdapter = new DetailsAdapter(Test.this, adapterList);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Test.this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        API service = ServiceGenerator.createService(API.class);
        call = service.getCategoriesData(String.valueOf(catid));

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                String urlResponse = Utils.convertTypedBodyToString(response);
                JSONObject json = null;
                JSONArray jsonResponse = null;
                Log.i("CatResponse - ", "" + urlResponse);
                //Log.i("CatResponse - ", "" + json);




                //CHECK THIS!
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(urlResponse);
                    //coverting arraylist to array
                    String[] stringArray = adapterList.toArray(new String[0]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                        DetailData current = new DetailData();
                        current.setPname(stringArray[i]);
                        // current.setImage(img[i]);
                        adapterList.add(current);
                    }

                    //return adapterList;
                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                     jsonResponse = json.getJSONArray("result");
                    Log.i("Array", "" + jsonResponse);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //PASS THE JSON ARRAY ONLY
                ArrayList<DetailData> itemList = null;
                Context context1 = null;
                //Log.i("CatResponse1 - ", "" + json);

                adapterList = getData(jsonResponse);
                DetailsAdapter da = new DetailsAdapter(context1, itemList);
                da.updatevalues(adapterList);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("RetroError - ", "" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });


    }


    public ArrayList<DetailData> getData(JSONArray details) {
        ArrayList<DetailData> data = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
            DetailData current = new DetailData();
            try {
                current.setImage(details.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
                current.setPdescr(details.getJSONObject(i).getString("pdescr"));
                current.setPname(details.getJSONObject(i).getString("pname"));
                current.setPprice(details.getJSONObject(i).getString("pprice"));
                data.add(current);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

**xml layouts**

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pprice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

response

```
{
    "result": [{
        "image": null,
        "pname": "Barshi Bed",
        "pprice": "20000",
        "pdescr": "Barshi bed Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }, {
        "image": null,
        "pname": "King bed nexa one",
        "pprice": "15000",
        "pdescr": "King bed nexa one Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }, {
        "image": null,
        "pname": "Royal Sofa",
        "pprice": "25000",
        "pdescr": "Royal Sofa Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }]
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: its is only the class show us json response

Comment: i have edited @KhizarHayat

Comment: You are not familiar with retrofit call well. first try some tutorials of retrofit

Comment: could u suggest me a better place fro wer i cn learn it?.. can u help me?

Comment: he just need some help..  why the downvote anyway?

Answer (score 0):

First create a model class called MyResponse.java

```
public class MyResponse implements Serializable {

  @Expose @SerializedName("result")
  private ArrayList<DetailData> listData;


  public ArrayList<DetailData> getListData() {
    return listData;
  }

  public void setListData(ArrayList<DetailData> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
  } 
}
```

And then on your interface Api.java change the call getCategoriesData type :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("")
Call<MyResponse> getCategoriesData(@Field("catid") String catid);
```

Lastly on your Activity.class :

1. change the call type :

   ```
   Call<MyResponse> call;
   ```
2. Change the enque :

   ```
   call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
           if (response.isSuccessful()) {
               String strBody = response.body().toString();
               Log.i("---- NEWS_REST_SERVICE response : " + strBody);
               MyResponse responsePojo = response.body();
               adapterList = responsePojo.getListData();

               rcAdapter = new DetailsAdapter(Test.this, adapterList);

               rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           } else {
               Log.i("---- NEWS_REST_SERVICE error response");
               int sc = response.code();
               switch (sc) {

               }
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
           Log.i("RetroError - ", "" + t.getMessage());
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: i tried your code but on click it doesnt display anything in the activity its blank!

Comment: I've added rcAdapter = new DetailsAdapter(Test.this, adapterList); maybe it will solve the problem

Comment: Did you use POST or GET method?

Comment: im using post 
Logcat gives this msg:---- NEWS_REST_SERVICE response : com.example.sshank.shree_decor.Model.MyResponse@1c0a8232

Comment: still not fixed? i'm so sorry... :(

Comment: My logcat ---- NEWS_REST_SERVICE response : Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.0.7/shree_decor/jsonfetch.php}

Comment: i finally can get the response.. it seem we need to save it to variable, i dont know why.. feel stupid

Comment: can u share the answer @Al Zill

Comment: no, i mean i can display the response for my own php files. I don't know what's the problem with yours. But maybe you can try my latest code above. I save the response to a string variable so that you can debug it in Logcat

Comment: or may be you can use tools like Rest Client for firefox to simulate POST request for your webservice. Because your php files seems like only can be accessed from your internal network.

Comment: can you pls share ur json script?
rajfor.shirodkar@gmail.com

Comment: No Success..:(.
But thanks @al zill u tried ur best to help! :)